# How to use underscore.js to find if a String is blank?

Tags: javascript, string, underscore.js

I am looking an equivalent of http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isBlank(java.lang.CharSequence)
I found several 3rd party extensions, but is there one out of the box with underscore.js: http://underscorejs.org

Comment: How about `string == null || string.trim().length === 0`? No libraries needed...

Comment: @RobW: I was looking for some sort of _.isBlank function. But your answer is right.

Comment: @downvoter: reason for your down vote would be appreciated.

Comment: @muistooshort that's exactly what I wanted. Thanks

Comment: !!{null:1,"":1," ":1}[string]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Following @muistooshort's advice I created my mixin and wanted to share it:

```
  _.mixin({
    isBlank: function(string) {
      return (_.isUndefined(string) || _.isNull(string) || string.trim().length === 0)
    }
  });

> _("\t").isBlank()
< true

> _("qwerty").isBlank()
< false
```

Answer (score 8):

```
_.isEmpty(_.trim(string));
```

This runs a null or empty string check.

Edited with update from ehftwelve

Comment: That doesn't get what OP is asking for, it'll return `false` for string `"   "`.

Answer (score 5):

```
function isBlank(str) {
  return !!(str||'').match(/^\s*$/);
}

isBlank(null);    // => true
isBlank('');      // => true
isBlank(' \t ');  // => true
isBlank(' foo '); // => false
```

Comment: Just curious, how does this answer compare to @Rob W's answer ?

Comment: @VenkatSudheerReddyAedama: very similar.  Performance differences will likely vary between interpreters but you could setup a jsPerf page to see.

Comment: Of course, there are likely corner cases galore! =P

Comment: very clever and short. mine has the only advantage to be more readable. don't know about performance.

Comment: This method also returns `true` for `isBlank(0);` and `isBlank(false);`. This is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

In Underscore.js you have `_.isEmpty` ( http://underscorejs.org/#isEmpty ) but it only checks if the array-like object or string has a length of 0.

If you want to check if a variable is a whitespace string, empty string or null (equivalent of java's isBlank) you should make your own function.

```
function isBlank(str) {

  if (str === null || str.length === 0 || str === " ") return true;
  return false;

}
```

Comment: you can make it work with tab spaces if you want... but you won't find it in Underscore.js

Answer (score 1):

using bind to create a native method:

```
var isBlank=/./.test.bind(/(^$)|(^null$)|(^\s+$)/); // bind a regexp to test()

_.map(["", " ", " x ", 0, null], isBlank ); // test it against various data
// == [true, true, false, false, true] // reflects java version output
```

Answer (score 0):

You could extend underscore.

```
  _.isBlank = function (str) {
        return !!(str||'').match(/^\s*$/);
    }
```

If you really don't want to create a function as taseenb 
mentioned use isEmpty with trim. Although this is ugly!

```
_.isEmpty('    '.trim());
```

Although both these don't work with tabbed spaces

Answer (score 0):

Here's my snippet that I used when checking empty strings.

```
    _.isBlank = function (str) {
       return (!str || /^\s*$/.test(str));
    }

    var strs = ['a', 1, -1, 0, NaN, '', ' ', '\t', '\n', null, undefined];
    strs.forEach(function(s){
     console.log('is blank? ', s, _.isBlank(s));
    });
```

Note: The zero(0) will be considered as empty.